# Sharepoint Workflow - Column field folder

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I want to create a new item into an sharepoint list created by an sharepoint workflow which is fired when creating a new list item on another list. I'm creating the workflow on sharepoint Designer 2013 and the 2010th Workflow version.

There seems to be an "folder" column which needed to be set. But I don't know which content this field should have. When I don't set these value, the workflow gets aborted.

Thanks in advance

Addition: The sharepoint server reports me that at least on column has a wrong value type

Addition 2: When I manually start the workflow on that item, it runs properly.

Comment: What columns does your list contain?

Comment: Only the title column and a text column

Comment: Can you post here the steps and actions that you added to the wokflow (a screenshot would help) ?

Comment: At the moment does the workflow only contain a command to create a new item with values like "test"

Comment: does it have required fields?

Comment: It does not have any requried fields.